# Cannot find module '../internals/array-method-uses-to-length'

Tags: node-modules, npm-install, core-js

I am working on `Symfony5` project.
There is a following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../internals/array-method-uses-to-length'
```

In fact, the `array-method-uses-to-length` module is missing from `node_modules/core-js/internals` folder.

Inside `package.json` file core-js version: `3.33.0`.

I deleted 'node_modules' folder and 'package-lock.json' file.

Then I run `npm install` and `yarn install`, but it did not install `array-method-uses-to-length` module.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks in advance.